# Google Maps is blank [Android] Release Mode

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to release my android app, but I'm facing some problems.
When I use it on Debug Mode I can access the google map, but when I generate the release of the app, the map is blank.

I've been searching and I found out that there's another google maps api file in the release mode that I had to change, but even when I set my key in it, I still have the same problem.

Anyone any idea ?

Comment: Look up tutorials for generating a release key for Google maps for Android.

Comment: check your api key is enable or not

Comment: This is almost surely an API KEY problem. Check the LogCat output, there should be a warning or error indicating why the map won't display.

Comment: It is enabled, because I can run it in debug mode and I can see the map running, but it doesn't show up when I generate a release of the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For future readers!**

I found a solution on this video --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLJ0jDFdUZ0

The steps :

1. Create a new key
2. Generate a signature for my app
3. I run this command "keytool.exe -list -v -alias aliasname -keystore "keypath" -storepass password -keypass password
4. I changed the perspectives in Android Studio to Release Mode
5. I encountered the google maps api xml file, then I set the new key I had generated.
6. That's it, I hope it helps somebody later on. thank u all who tried to help me.